# How to get first available result from voice and keyboard inputs?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm trying to make a simple python program that is able to listen a text message from multiple sources.
For the moment I want to use stdin and a voice recognizer.
The idea is that the user is capable of inserting text either with voice or keyboard, and when one is ready the value is returned.

so I have something like this:

```
def keyboard_input():
   return input()

def voice_input():
   return listener.listen()

def method():
   output = ''
   # Listen from keyboard_input and voice_input
   ...
   # Input received from one source, terminate the other one
   return output
```

I'm trying with threads, like to run the two input methods in separated threads, however I'm struggling with the return and kill part.

**Edited, more details on the methods:**

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def listen():
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print("Listening:...")
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)
    try:
        text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="it-IT")
        return text
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def write():
    print('Insert text...')
    text = input()
    print(text)
    return text


OUTPUT = None
# Code to run at the same time listen and write on a common variable OUTPUT,
#...
# If one of them gives the output the other method should terminate

print(OUTPUT)
```

Comment: So I guess your question is actually: "How to get first available result from voice and keyboard inputs ?" Right ? Could you please edit to make it (more) clear ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install v_input package ? 
You can install this package by copying this code on your Anaconda Prompt:

```
!pip-install -v_input
```